# How to add onclick event on checkbox in ember (hbs)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been added to the project with Ember. Unfortunately I only know AngularJS. Anyway, what I have to do is to add `onclick` event on the checkbox. I've tried to use observer but without much success (probably because input is generated via iteration). Here's the code

```
{{#each prod in allProducts}}
    <tr>
       <td class="checkbox-event" selenium-id="check">{{input type=checkbox checked=prod.selected id=prod.id}}</td>
       <td selenium-id="id">{{prod.productNumber}}</td>
       <td selenium-id="name">{{prod.name}}</td>
       <td selenium-id="category">{{prod.mainCategoryName}}</td>
       <td selenium-id="price">{{prod.mainPrice}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

What I need to do is to add a click event on input that will call some function with `prod` as argument. I have only found answers for 'normal' input but not the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. `each prod in allProducts` is wrong. Use `{{#each allProducts as |prod|}}`
2. `type=checkbox` is wrong. Use `type="checkbox"`
3. you can use `change` action.

   Checkout this [twiddle link](https://ember-twiddle.com/daa5cb4e9de39a79c8227a2551d5cbc9?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: Hey sorry that I didn't mention that but I have ember 1.7 version. When trying to add with your way I have an error in console on `change=(action...' saying that it expected 'STRING' etc

Comment: @ojciecmatki just change the input line with this `<input type="checkbox" checked={{prod.selected}} id={{prod.id}} {{action 'myhandler' prod on="change"}} > ` in Ahmet's twiddle.